# validation file size does not work in Yii client vallidation

Tags: php, validation, yii

I dont understand why the file size rule is not working in Yii.  I've followed instructions of the official documentation. I've checked the questions in stackoverflow but I did not find any response.

My form contains:

```
<?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'posts-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        ),
    ));
    ?>
.....

<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>  
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'image'); ?>
    </div>
```

my rules the model is this

```
array('image', 'file',
                  'maxFiles'=>1,
                  'maxSize'=>1024 * 1, 
                  'tooLarge'=>'Not more than 1MB'),
```

If I want to upload a file with a size > 1Mb  ,  no errors is displayed and the file is saved in file system.  Why the error message is not displayed?

I must add that I have a rule on the same field (image) which test by reg expression the file type,  and it works fine,  it displays the error message when file format is wrong.

Comment: maybe adding the code of how you save the file would help

Comment: @Asped I've read that given that the file system is not accessible by client. Now I choose a different method.  In my controller, I check the file size in the controller

Comment: Please note thet the size is specified in bytes, so you would probably need 1014 * 1024.